# Unhandled exceptions on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have this code:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += HandleAndroidException;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());

    }

    private void HandleAndroidException(object sender, RaiseThrowableEventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).Path + "logerror.txt");
        sw.WriteLine(e.Exception.ToString());
        sw.Close();           
    }
```

It's working, but I want in HandleAndroidException show AlertDialog with informations of exception, so I wrote this code:

```
 private void HandleAndroidException(object sender, RaiseThrowableEventArgs e)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.SetMessage(e.ToString());
        builder1.SetCancelable(true);
        AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.Create();
        alert11.Show();
    }
```

And... It's not working. I think that use AlertDialog is not allowed, when application throw exception - it's true? Is there a way for show information about exception by application (in DialogBox) when app throw unhandled exception?

Comment: change `AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.Create();` to `AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();` this will work @luki

Comment: I'm writting in Xamarin, so this method is Create(), and this code working if I run it in other place of code. It's not working only when app throw Exception...

Comment: Sorry man, I don't have knowledge of Xamarin may be someone who have any idea helps you! Happy Coding

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: I generate artificial exception by throw new Exception () for test method HandleAndroidException. Code in HandleAndroidException not throwing exception ... app just turn down.

Comment: I have the same problem in UWP project. When I call: var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(e.UnhandledError.ToString());
await dialog.ShowAsync(); in method called by CoreApplication.UnhandledErrorDetected event, dialogBox is not showed... But if I call the same code in other place of code - all is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want in HandleAndroidException show AlertDialog with informations of exception

You cant use `AlertDialog` show the error message. Here is an alternative choice, you could display an `Activity` as a dialog to show the error message.

I wrote up a simple demo about how to implement this feature, effect like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n55x2.gif). You can see it in this [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/aixiaozi/ExecptionDemo). Here is my code :

Catch the exception :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += HandleAndroidException;

    base.OnCreate(bundle);
}
```

Open a new `Activity` to show error message :

```
private void HandleAndroidException(object sender, RaiseThrowableEventArgs e)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(CrashDialog));
    intent.PutExtra("Error_Text", e.ToString());
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    this.StartActivity(intent);
    Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Exit(0);// Close this app process
}
```

Use this `CrashDialog`  activity as a dialog :

```
[Activity(
    Label = "CrashDialog", 
    LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask,
    Theme = "@style/alert_dialog", 
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Keyboard| ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden|ConfigChanges.Navigation),
    ]
public class CrashDialog : Activity
{
    private Button btnExit, btnRestart;
    public string errorMessage;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_crash);
        errorMessage = Intent.GetStringExtra("Error_Text");
        this.SetFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
        InitView();
    }

    private void InitView()
    {
        btnExit = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.cash_exit);
        btnExit.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Exit();
        };
        btnRestart = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.cash_restart);
        btnRestart.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Restart();
        };
        TextView errorText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.content);
        errorText.Text = errorMessage;
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        base.OnBackPressed();
        Exit();
    }

    private void Exit()
    {
        Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Exit(0);
        Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
    }

    private void Restart()
    {
        Intent intent = BaseContext.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(BaseContext.PackageName);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        StartActivity(intent);
        Exit();
    }
}
```

Its style :

```
<style name="alert_dialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.4</item>
</style>
```